# Simple winsock server acting unreliablely

Tags: c, winsock

I have the following simple winsock server written in plain C:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NETWORK_ERROR -1
#define NETWORK_OK     0

int IP = INADDR_ANY;
int port = 8888;

SOCKET listeningSocket;
SOCKET client;

void error(const char *);
void error(const char *functionName) {
    char errorMsg[92];
    ZeroMemory(errorMsg, 92);

    sprintf(errorMsg, "Call to %s returned error %d!", (char *)functionName, WSAGetLastError());

    MessageBox(NULL, errorMsg, "socketIndication", MB_OK);

    closesocket(client);
    closesocket(listeningSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmd, int nShow) {

    WSADATA wsaData;
    int nret;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData);

    char hostName[80];
    if(gethostname(hostName, sizeof(hostName)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        error("gethostname()");
        return NETWORK_ERROR;
    }

    printf("Started Server\n");
    printf("Running on: %s\n", hostName);

    listeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(listeningSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error("socket()");
        return NETWORK_ERROR;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN serverInfo;

    serverInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(port);

    nret = bind(listeningSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)&serverInfo, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    if(nret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        error("bind()");
        return NETWORK_ERROR;
    }

    while(client != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        nret = listen(listeningSocket, 10);
        printf("Listening for incoming requests\n");

        if(nret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            error("listen()");
            return NETWORK_ERROR;
        }

        client = accept(listeningSocket, NULL, NULL);

        char buffer[256];
        ZeroMemory(buffer, 256);

        strcpy(buffer, "Pretend this is important data.");

        nret = send(client, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

        if(nret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            error("send()");
            return NETWORK_ERROR;
        }

        printf("Sent some data\n");

        closesocket(client);
    }

    error("accept()");
    return NETWORK_ERROR;
}
```

Most of it was followed from this tutorial:

http://johnnie.jerrata.com/winsocktutorial/

However the server seems to be a hit and miss. When I visit http://[My IP]:8888/ in my browser, half of the time I'll get the response "Pretend this is important data." as intended, however the other half of the time I get either "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." or "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at [My IP]:8888.".

So is there anything wrong with my code which can be causing this?

Comment: Well, one problem may be that you are testing it with Firefox, using http. Your code is not using the http protocol in sending its response. You might try testing with telnet or something similar.

Comment: It almost qualifies as HTTP/0.9 but it doesn't read the request from the client before sending. If the server finishes writing the response and closes the socket before the arrival of the packet containing the client's request, that packet arriving at a closed socket will generate a reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to listen() should be outside of the loop. The only socket calls you're going to want in the loop are accept() to get the client socket, and reading, writing, and finally closing the client socket.

Also, if you want the program to work with Firefox you'll have to implement the relevant parts of the HTTP protocol, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: This, in addition to what Wumpus W. Wumbley suggested worked! Well, 1% of the time it will randomly display the error, but other than that it's fine. Thanks.

Comment: I have also noticed that using a more obscure port like 5473 instead of the traditional port 80 or 8888 reduces the frequency of these bugs tremendously.